# Spring dynamic language support with transactions

Tags: java, spring, groovy

In the current application I am working on we feel the need to re-evaluate some DAO logic on the fly, without the need for a new deploy.
For this I choose to try the Spring-Groovy integration.
I've got the beans wired and in the Groovy scripts I can get a handle of the the javax.sql.Datasource object. 
But I have a problem when a transactional operation happens, for instance if I make a insert in some java-style DAO the row is not visible in the groovy-style DAO even if it's called from the same service marked as `@Transactional`.
I will try to put some relevant piece of code, if any other details are needed I can provide.

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BaseConfig.class);

    TestService ts = ctx.getBean(TestService.class);
    ts.testGroovy();

}
```

}

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

@Autowired
private HibernateDAO hibernateDAO;

@Autowired
private OtherDAO otherDAO;

@Autowired
private Groovy groovy;

@Override
public void testGroovy() {
    hibernateDAO.makeInsert(); //actually now it makes a jdbc insert, no need for flush session
    //throw new RuntimeException("error");
    groovy.testInjection();
    otherDAO.verifyInsert();
  }
}
```

The java DAO:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateDAOImpl implements HibernateDAO{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;


@Override
public void makeInsert() {
    Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into GROOVY_TEST values(?,?)");
        ps.setLong(1, System.currentTimeMillis());
        ps.setString(2, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The interface used for proxy:

```
public interface Groovy {
   void testInjection();
}
```

For injecting the Datasource in Groovy I extended a java class that autowired the Datasource instance.

```
public abstract class GroovyHelper implements Groovy{

 @Autowired 
 private DataSource dataSource;

 public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
 }  
}
```

The groovy file:

```
import ro.asf.groovy.GroovyHelper
import javax.sql.DataSource
import groovy.sql.Sql

class GroovyImpl extends GroovyHelper {

void testInjection() {
    //throw new RuntimeException("error")
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.eachRow('''SELECT * FROM GROOVY_TEST ''', { article ->
        println article.value
    })
}    
}
```

And the xml file for wiring the groovy script to spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd">

    <lang:groovy id="groovy" script-source="file:scripts/Groovy.groovy" />

</beans>
```

In the verify DAO layer the insert is seen as expected.

Thank you,

Daniel